# .Passing variable value from one namespace to another

Tags: c#

This is my Namespace App program which calculate days between two days.

```
namespace App
internal class Program
{
    public static void Main()
    {
        DateTime dj;
        Console.WriteLine("Enter your joining date(DD-MM-YYYY):");
        string input = Console.ReadLine();
        string[] formats = { "d-M-yyyy", "d-MM-yyyy", "dd-M-yyyy", "dd-MM-yyyy" };
        dj = DateTime.ParseExact(input, formats, System.Globalization.CultureInfo.InvariantCulture, System.Globalization.DateTimeStyles.None);
        DateTime now = DateTime.Now;

        DayUtility du = new DayUtility();
        du.validate(dj, now);
        double result = du.Calculate(dj, now);
        Console.WriteLine("Total working days is:" + result);

        Console.ReadLine();
    }
}
```

2.This is my another namespace IncentiveApp which calculate the incentive bases on the total workin days.

```
namespace IncentiveApp
{
    internal class IncentiveUtility
    {
        public int calculate(int rate)
        {
            int r = rate;
            int q = quantity;
            int result = r * q;
            return result;
        }
    }
}
```

I want to get the `result` value from `IncentiveApp` namespace to copy into quantity variable in `App` namespace. How can I do this?

Comment: Well where are you declaring `quantity` at all in `IncentiveUtility`? Perhaps you should add it as another parameter?

Answer (score 0):

In your "App" namespace file add

```
using IncentiveApp;
```

Then you can access the class IncentiveUtility from within your "App" namespace.